# Expo production build issues (Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, expo, production

I tried to run a production build locally by executing  `expo start --no-dev --minify`.

All that renders is the initial template file that says "Open up App.tsx to start working on your app" and none of my work shows up...
I'm curious if someone else has experienced this and came up with a solution?

In the **package.json** I reference following file:

```
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
```

**AppEntry.js:**

```
import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';

import App from '../../App';

registerRootComponent(App);
```

I have a file in my root of my project that is called App.tsx, but it's written in typescript. Might there be an issue with that import?

Another thing I don't understand is where the production build gets the information for the initial template file... This file does not exist in my project anymore.

I thought there might be a caching issue, so tried to run the command with the `--clear` argument, but this didn't seem to help at all.

**FYI:**
EXPO SDK: 48
I don't run the application in an emulator, I execute it through the Expo GO App on Android.

**Things I tried:**

- I just found out that it works on the web without any issues.
- I compared the typescript-tutorial-project with mine and made a few changes, it still doesnt work.(https://github.com/expo/examples/tree/master/with-typescript)
- I removed the reference in the package.json for the main file, because it's not included in the typescript-template

Answer (score 0):

After deleting `node_modules`, `android` and `.expo` directories, and then running commands to recreate these directories by:

```
npm start --no-dev --minify
```

everything runs correctly for me.